# How to describe a program written by the author?

Tags: publications

If we build a setup at the lab, we describe it as home-built when we write the paper. What is the correct word to describe a program written by the author? The program has not been published and there is no intention to do so.

Comment: Would home-built not _also_ be suitable?

Comment: Alternatively, maybe _custom_?

Comment: Utilizing proprietary software we.....

Comment: @scrappedcola [Proprietary typically describes the ownership of the IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proprietary_software). You could have non-proprietary software you developed yourself, and proprietary software which someone else developed.

Comment: prototype is the term I usually use for that

Comment: @FábioDias Prototype would imply that the software was in an early, potentially unfinished, form. Nothing the OP has said suggests this is the case. More importantly, prototype also says nothing about who wrote the software.

Comment: @Ian_Fin 'proprietary' seems very accurate in this regard, as "has not been published and there is no intention to do so" matches sole ownership of IP and not distributing it freely. Other than that, "in-house software" seems to be used more often than "home-built" which carries connotations of something developed *outside* the lab/company at your own home.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"in-house" program is the term I always use myself and see in other people's papers.

In the corporate context, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-house_software) defines it as

> In-house software is a software that is produced by a corporate entity for purpose of using it within the organization.

[Here's an example](https://books.google.de/books?id=6F3VpyF0EUMC&pg=PA116&lpg=PA116&dq=in-house%20molecular%20dynamics&source=bl&ots=X0Aatcp78y&sig=3R2aRDqxO44WiEjqHlDHapHjHmo&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiuhf2PhOnPAhWCVRQKHez5DkgQ6AEIVjAH#v=onepage&q=in-house%20molecular%20dynamics&f=false) in an academic context

> Energy minimization is done with yammp, an in-house molecular mechanics package.

[Here's another example from academia](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0969212610003539)

> All analyses were done with a battery of in-house codes and external analytical tools.

I wouldn't say "in-house" strictly means "the source code is private". I have sometimes seen people use "in-house" to mean "code our own research group wrote and uses, but which we also make available as open-source code". But if I see a sentence in an article like "All analysis was performed using in-house code", and no reference, then I read it as "We used some code we wrote ourselves which we haven't published anywhere", which sounds like what you want.